# Windows 10 registry access

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I have an old Windows program that reads information from the registry, like so:

```
CRegKey rkey;

if(rkey.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\xxx\\yyy", KEY_READ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    ...
}
```

On a Windows 10 locked down user account, this fails!

It cannot even read the registry, at least not that part of it.

I've looked on Microsoft's support site, and I could not find where it addresses this.

Can anyone point me to info, or just tell me, how accessing the registry from a (C++) program is affected by UAC in Windows 10?

Comment: Well, fix your code, you cannot tell *why* it failed.  Google "windows registry redirector".

Comment: Use `regedit`: in the tree pane right click the node(s) you are interested in and check their permissions.  You old windows program is most likely assuming it is running with admin privileges, on a Windows 10 machine it will only have user rights.

Comment: Can you specify the registry key that you are trying to access?

Comment: What error code is `open()` returning?

Comment: "*On a Windows 10 locked down user account, this fails!*" - fails HOW exactly?  What is the actual return value of `Open()`? That will tell you WHY it failed. Also, always request the *least* amount of rights you actually need. If you are just trying to read values, use `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` instead of `KEY_READ`, which includes other rights (`STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ`, `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, and `KEY_NOTIFY`) that you don't need and may not have permissions to use.

Answer (score 0):

I need to retract this question. Further investigation shows that the User account has read access to HKLM etc in the registry, and that is not the problem. In fact, the installer already wrote the registry entries I was looking for under HKCU (current user) where User account has both R and W permission.  ...  So, I blamed Windows 10 user mode unnecessarily.  Issue seems to be communication from that program to another is not succeeding. We will look into it. I apologize for posting the question which, on investigation, turned out not to be the source of the problem.

Comment: To retract the question, just delete it. There's a link to do this below your question.